# How to duplicate groups of rows in Pandas based on number in column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame (df) that looks like this:

```
+-----------------------------  +
| aid | bid | x1  | x2  | count |
+-----------------------------  +
| 1   | 1   | tim | 6   | 3     |
| 1   | 2   | tim | 6   | 3     |
| 1   | 3   | tim | 6   | 3     |
| 2   | 1   | bob | 6   | 2     |
| 2   | 2   | bob | 6   | 2     |
| 2   | 3   | bob | 6   | 2     |
+-----------------------------  +
```

I need to generate a new data frame where each group (grouped on 'aid') is duplicated by the number in the 'count' column.  It should look like this:

```
+-----------------------------  +
| aid | bid | x1  | x2  | count |
+-----------------------------  +
| 1   | 1   | tim | 6   | 3     |
| 1   | 2   | tim | 6   | 3     |
| 1   | 3   | tim | 6   | 3     |
| 1   | 1   | tim | 6   | 3     |
| 1   | 2   | tim | 6   | 3     |
| 1   | 3   | tim | 6   | 3     |
| 1   | 1   | tim | 6   | 3     |
| 1   | 2   | tim | 6   | 3     |
| 1   | 3   | tim | 6   | 3     |
| 2   | 1   | bob | 6   | 2     |
| 2   | 2   | bob | 6   | 2     |
| 2   | 3   | bob | 6   | 2     |
| 2   | 1   | bob | 6   | 2     |
| 2   | 2   | bob | 6   | 2     |
| 2   | 3   | bob | 6   | 2     |
+-----------------------------  +
```

I can't seem to get this to work using the split-apply-combine methods in pandas.

I am been able to split the groups 
    df.groupby('aid', sort=False)
but can't get past this step.
thanks for any help.

UPDATED: Both the answers by B.M. and Alexander worked with the example data I provided.  I have subsequently learned that the data I provided was not realistic enough to work with my real data.  Let me provide an updated dataset.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'aid': [1,1,1,2,2,2], 'bid': [1,2,3,1,2,3], 'x1':    ['tim']*3 + ['bob']*3 + ['ray']*3, 'x2': [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1], 'count': [3,3,3,2,2,2,4,4,4]})[['aid', 'bid', 'x1', 'x2', 'count']]

    aid  bid  x1    x2     count
0    1    1   tim   1      3
1    1    2   tim   0      3
2    1    3   tim   0      3
3    2    1   bob   0      2
4    2    2   bob   1      2
5    2    3   bob   0      2
6    3    1   ray   0      4
7    3    2   ray   0      4
8    3    3   ray   1      4
```

Now when I run Alexander's solution I get the output shown below.  I need to have output first sorted by 'aid' and then 'bid' where bid always repeats 1,2,3 while keeping the value of X2 that was associated with that 'bid' in original data before duplicating the groups of three rows.

```
pd.concat([frame 
           for count, frame in df.groupby('count', as_index=False,sort=False) 
           for _ in range(count)]).sort_values('aid').reset_index(drop=True)

    aid  bid   x1   x2     count
0     1    1  tim   1      3
1     1    2  tim   0      3
2     1    3  tim   0      3
3     1    1  tim   1      3
4     1    2  tim   0      3
5     1    3  tim   0      3
6     1    1  tim   1      3
7     1    2  tim   0      3
8     1    3  tim   0      3
9     2    3  bob   0      2
10    2    1  bob   0      2
11    2    2  bob   1      2
12    2    2  bob   1      2
13    2    1  bob   0      2
14    2    3  bob   0      2
15    3    2  ray   0      4
16    3    1  ray   0      4
17    3    2  ray   0      4
18    3    3  ray   1      4
19    3    1  ray   0      4
20    3    2  ray   0      4
21    3    3  ray   1      4
22    3    1  ray   0      4
23    3    2  ray   0      4
24    3    3  ray   1      4
25    3    1  ray   0      4
26    3    3  ray   1      4
```

In this output it sorted correctly for the first 'bid' observations (ie 1,2,3,1,2,3 ...) but then the ordering falls apart further down.  There must be small tweak I am missing.  I really do appreciate any further thoughts on this.

Using the example provided by B.M. it provides the right answer sorted by the repeating 'bid' (ie 1,2,3,1,2,3...) but then that is lost when sorting by 'aid'.

thanks for any suggestions on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate using a list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'aid': [1,1,1,2,2,2], 'bid': [1,2,3,1,2,3], 'x1': ['tim']*3 + ['bob']*3, 'x2': [6]*6, 'count': [3,3,3,2,2,2]})[['aid', 'bid', 'x1', 'x2', 'count']]

>>> pd.concat([frame 
               for count, frame in df.groupby('count', as_index=False, sort=False) 
               for _ in range(count)]).sort_values('aid').reset_index(drop=True)
    aid  bid   x1  x2  count
0     1    1  tim   6      3
1     1    2  tim   6      3
2     1    3  tim   6      3
3     1    1  tim   6      3
4     1    2  tim   6      3
5     1    3  tim   6      3
6     1    1  tim   6      3
7     1    2  tim   6      3
8     1    3  tim   6      3
9     2    1  bob   6      2
10    2    2  bob   6      2
11    2    3  bob   6      2
12    2    1  bob   6      2
13    2    2  bob   6      2
14    2    3  bob   6      2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
out=pd.DataFrame()
for n,fr in df.groupby('count'): out=out.append([fr]*n)
```

for

```
In [5]: out.sort('aid')
Out[5]: 
   aid  bid   x1  x2  count
0    1    1  tim   6      3
1    1    2  tim   6      3
2    1    3  tim   6      3
0    1    1  tim   6      3
1    1    2  tim   6      3
2    1    3  tim   6      3
0    1    1  tim   6      3
1    1    2  tim   6      3
2    1    3  tim   6      3
3    2    1  bob   6      2
4    2    2  bob   6      2
5    2    3  bob   6      2
3    2    1  bob   6      2
4    2    2  bob   6      2
5    2    3  bob   6      2
```